# Best of Code Review 2016 - Best Newcomer (question) category

Tags: discussion, fun, best-of

Please post your nominations for the [Best of Code Review 2016 - Best Newcomer (question)](/a/7105) category.

> *Best question by a user who had not posted a question before 2016.*

In your nomination post, please make sure to include a link to the nominated question. Include a short explanation of what makes the question exceptional.

The following [SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/611421/best-of-code-review-best-newcomer-question-category) will show all potential candidates.

---

<sub>**Small characters at the bottom:**
Only one nomination per post. Nominated questions must have a creation date in 2016. Downvotes don't count. Santa reserves the right to award the top-voted nominee a special bounty as a token of appreciation on behalf of the Code Review community.</sub>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Disproving Euler proposition by brute force in C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/145221/34073) by [Aidenhjj](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/121212/aidenhjj).  This question follows the format of a good CR question: A clear description of the problem, the code, and a set of concerns to be addressed.  It was the first question asked by the user, and went very hot, garnering 19 answers (2 deleted).

Comment: Literally no idea why my question was so popular. Thanks for the vote of confidence!

Comment: @Aidenhjj it had 29 lines of clear written code, and several different points of view were possible, e.g. pure mathematical approaches, caching, fixing boundaries, using better functions, proper types. And I still haven't covered multi-threading in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

[Hexadecimal command line file viewer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115661/34073) by [Daniel Gee](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/90237/daniel-gee).  This first post is a good CR question, with a concise description of the problem and the code.  It did not go as hot as my other nomination, perhaps because there was less scope for improving the code, but it is, nonetheless, just as good of a question.

Answer (score 2):

[Python ASCII-Art Table](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144755/python-ascii-art-table) by [Uriel Eli](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/120759/uriel-eli). The first question of a serie of 3 about ascii representation of various things; which make each of them very clean. The description may be considered succint but exposes the requirements quite clearly. The question also feature a demo of the code which makes it more attractive.

Answer (score 1):

[Implemenation for concurrent file access (read/write)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/133763/4203) by [JanDotNet](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/104803/jandotnet), one of the more active newcomers that I have noticed this year, is another question I found appealing.  This question states its requirements clearly and is clearly looking for a review.  The concurrent nature of the problem was appealing and kept me pondering the question for days.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Battle game in one 900-line class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/144601/4203) by [user120597](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/120597/user120597) a strangely appealing question.  The question itself was self-contained and runnable.  The [title added by 200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/144601/3) tells you everything you need to know about the code, which is self explanatory.  The code itself had a lot of scope of different types of improvement which meant it appealed from different perspectives and had an appealing **just one more thing** about it.